# Comparing values from tables

Tags: php, database

In my database, I have two tables `A` and `B`.

`A` has two columns named image and name, where I upload image and store its name.

`B` has only image. (I select few images from `A` and insert it to `B` via front end )

`B` is like a subset of `A`.

I want `B` to be like image and name for the particular selected images.
So my question is whether I can compare these two tables and insert name in table `B` for those selected images.

Comment: you can simply build query select table_b.images As images ,table_a.name As name from table_b LEFT JOIN table_a 
ON table_b .images = table_a.images ;

Comment: thanks man.. its working